# PHP/PDO insert current date plus one month into MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, date, insert

I am trying to add the current date (not time if i have the option) and also the date of one month later into my MYSQL database and I keep gettin the following error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_LNUMBER in *myfile* on line 45
```

My function to insert the data is as follows:

```
function add_zipcode($zip, $adminID, $email)
{
    global $db;
    $query = '

        INSERT INTO zip_owners (zip, email, adminID, started, transferred, expires)
        VALUES (:zip, :email, :adminID, :started, :transferred, :expires)';
    try{
        $statement = $db->prepare($query);
        $statement->bindValue(':zip', $zip);
        $statement->bindValue(':email', $email);
        $statement->bindValue(':adminID', $adminID);
        $statement->bindValue(':started', now());

        $statement->bindValue(':transferred', now());
        $statement->bindValue(':expires', DATE_ADD(now(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH));
        $statement->execute();
        $statement->closeCursor();
    }
    catch (PDOexception $e) 
    {
        $error_message = $e->getMessage();
        echo "<p>Database Error: $error_message </p>";
        exit();
    }
}
```

The problem line is this one:

```
$statement->bindValue(':expires', DATE_ADD(now(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH));
```

I'm not quite sure why that syntax doesn't work.

My goal is to be able to compare the dates when selecting rows to return the rows that have the expires filed within a week of the current date.

Comment: I really wonder why do people down vote questions like this. And they do not sometimes give reasons for down voting and also they do not answer . The down voters tell us whats wrong with this question ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Quote your MySQL statements, they're strings in PHP:

```
$statement->bindValue(':expires', 'DATE_ADD(now(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)');
```