# How to insert things like "now() -interval '2 minutes'" into PHP PDO query?

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo

I have a query like this: (on Postgresql 8.4, PHP-fpm 5.3.10 (fpm-fcgi))

```
select * from users where now() - interval '2 minutes' < seenlast ORDER BY seenlast;
```

I would like to use PHP/PDO query, so:

```
$mymin=5; //this is a variable can be changed by $_GET
$query = $db_conn->prepare("select * from users where now() - interval ':myminute minutes' < seenlast ORDER BY seenlast"); 
$query->bindParm(":myminute",$mymin)
$query->execute;
```

This does't work, I cant find a way to pass the minutes(**$mymin**) in a proper way. If I hardcode the timestuff everithing works, so the other part of the code must be correct.

I also tried:

```
$temp=$mymin." minutes";
$query = $db_conn->prepare("select * from users where now() - interval :myminute < seenlast ORDER BY seenlast"); 
$query->bindParm(":myminute",$temp)
```

[I already saw this, didn't help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067782/php-pdo-insert-current-date-plus-one-month-into-mysql)

Comment: I had the same problem but received error: `SQLSTATE[HY105]: Invalid parameter type: 7`. This was because I had more params than the detected replacements (question marks) when using unnamed params.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Intervals can be multiplied by numbers. So one approach to this is to prepare the statement saying `interval '1 minute' * :myminutes` instead, passing the "myminutes" parameter as a simple integer.

Answer (score 9):

I don't know much PDO or PHP but I think I know what's going wrong here.

When you say this:

```
interval '3 minutes'
```

You're really performing a cast operation that's the same as:

```
'3 minutes'::interval
cast('3 minutes' as interval)
```

So what you're doing is casting a TEXT value to an INTERVAL. That means that you need to produce something that looks like the string `'3 minutes'`. You could paste the string pieces together using string concatenation:

```
# Use cast to make the precedence cleaner.
$query = $db_conn->prepare("select * from users where now() - cast(:myminute || ' minutes' as interval) < seenlast ORDER BY seenlast"); 
$query->bindParm(":myminute", $mymin)
```

Or you should be able to do the string wrangling in PHP:

```
$query = $db_conn->prepare("select * from users where now() - interval :myminute < seenlast ORDER BY seenlast"); 
$query->bindParm(":myminute", $mymin . ' minutes')
```

Comment: It was a long day, tomorrow I will also check this.

Comment: `cast(:interval as interval)` worked for me, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I have been struggling with Phalcon and its inner Models PDO parser for hours with the same problem.

I found this solution:

```
public static function getTimedoutRequests($secsThreshold) {
    return self::find(
        array(
            // PDO is buggy here, can't use INTERVAL
            "DATE_PART('epoch', create_time) < DATE_PART('epoch', NOW()) - ?0",
            "bind" => array(
                $secsThreshold
            )
        )
    );
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
... - INTERVAL :myminute MINUTES ...
```

without the quotes is the proper method. If it helps, think of the placeholders as the equivalent of use old-school variable-based query building methods

```
... - INTERVAL $myminute MINUTES
```

except the placeholders take care of the injection vulnerabilities that the variables don't. Just because you're using placeholders doesn't mean you can change SQL syntax, so

```
... - INTERVAL '2 minutes'
... - INTERVAL ':myminute minute'
```

are not valid SQL.

---

followup for mu:

```
mysql> select now() + interval '2 minute';
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
mysql> select now() + interval 2 minute;
+---------------------------+
| now() + interval 2 minute |
+---------------------------+
| 2013-01-22 13:38:24       |
+---------------------------+
1 row in set (0.02 sec)
```

Comment: I doubt `INTERVAL :myminute MINUTES` will work, I'd expect that to produce a syntax error. `INTERVAL '2 minutes'` OTOH is perfectly fine; `interval '3 minutes'` is a cast operation and the just another way of writing `'3 minutes'::interval` or `cast('3 minutes' as interval)`.

Comment: @MarcB: the question is about postgresql, though, in which case muistooshort is right.