# Using named placeholders with interval fails in PHP and PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, pdo, prepared-statement

Okay I've confirmed this works explicitly with PHP.

```
$ php --version
PHP 5.6.16 (cli) (built: Dec 30 2015 15:09:50) (DEBUG)

<pdo version>
pdo_pgsql
PDO Driver for PostgreSQL   enabled
PostgreSQL(libpq) Version   9.4.0
Module version  1.0.2
Revision    $Id: fe003f8ab9041c47e97784d215c2488c4bda724d $
```

I would like to recreate the following SQL in PHP using PDO:

```
UPDATE relationships SET status = 4 WHERE created > NOW() - interval '2 seconds';
```

This script is working:

```
<?php

$db = new PDO('pgsql:dbname=db;host=localhost;user=stevetauber');
$stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE relationships SET status = 4 WHERE created > NOW() - interval '?'");
$stmt->execute(array("2 seconds"));
```

Here it is with named placeholders:

```
<?php

$db = new PDO('pgsql:dbname=db;host=localhost;user=stevetauber');
$stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE relationships SET status = 4 WHERE created > NOW() - interval ':blah'");
$stmt->execute(array(":blah" => "2 seconds"));
```

Which gives this error:

```
Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: :blah in ... line 5
```

---

Now according to [PHP documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php),

> Example #6 Invalid use of placeholder:

```
 <?php
 $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM REGISTRY where name LIKE '%?%'");
 $stmt->execute(array($_GET['name']));

 // placeholder must be used in the place of the whole value
 $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM REGISTRY where name LIKE ?");
 $stmt->execute(array("%$_GET[name]%"));
 ?>
```

Here is the updated code:

```
<?php

$db = new PDO('pgsql:dbname=db;host=localhost;user=stevetauber');
$stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE relationships SET status = 4 WHERE created > NOW() - :blah");
$stmt->execute(array(":blah" => "interval '2 seconds'"));
```

Which yields these DB errors (no script errors):

```
ERROR:  operator does not exist: timestamp with time zone > interval at character 51
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
STATEMENT:  UPDATE relationships SET status = 4 WHERE created > NOW() - $1
```

PDO is doing something weird here though because:

```
# select NOW() - interval '2 seconds' as a , pg_typeof(NOW() - interval '2 seconds') as b;
               a               |            b             
-------------------------------+--------------------------
 2015-12-30 18:02:20.956453+00 | timestamp with time zone
(1 row)
```

So how do I use named placeholders with PostgreSQL and interval?

Comment: Why do you want to use named placeholders? From PDO wiki `Use named placeholders only if you need a complex query or if you already have an associative array which keys are equal to table field names. Otherwise, regular placeholders are simpler to use.`

Comment: What about `UPDATE relationships SET status = 4 WHERE created > NOW() - INTERVAL :bla` and binding `:bla` as `2 seconds`?

Comment: @davidstrachan I've greatly simplified the query to simplify the problem. My real query is extremely long and complicated

Comment: @julp Postgres requires the quotations, there is an error with that format.

Comment: After test, like Daniel Vérité said, "at least" a cast is needed (`UPDATE relationships SET status = 4 WHERE created > NOW() - :bla::interval` with `:bla` binded as `2 seconds`)

Answer (score 7):

Placeholders are for pure values, not for values decorated with units (or with anything else).

To express `interval '2 seconds'` in a placeholder, there are two options:

- in the query, write `:secs * interval '1 second'`
  and bind `:secs` to a number in php
- or write: `cast(:mystring as interval)`, and bind `:mystring` to the string `'2 seconds'`. It will be interpreted dynamically through the explicit cast.

---

When experimenting with the psql command line client to compare with the PDO driver, use the `PREPARE` and `EXECUTE` SQL statements with postgres native `$N` placeholders, as opposed to having the parameters values already written  literally in the query. This will match what the PHP driver is essentially doing when `PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES` is set to false.

In the last part of you question, when trying this in psql (your query, just simplified to not need a table):

```
select now() > now() - interval '2 seconds';
```

it does work and returns 't' (true).

But if you tried that:

```
prepare p as select now() > now() - $1;
```

if would fail with

> ERROR:  operator does not exist: timestamp with time zone > interval

which is the same error as with PDO's prepare/execute.

On the other hand, this does work:

```
=> prepare p as select now() > now() - interval '1 second'*$1;
PREPARE

=> execute p(2);
?column? 
----------
t
```

Comment: The multiplication seems hacky to me. Is there anyway to get this to be properly casted: `prepare p as select now() > now() - $1;`?

Comment: Okay so this works: `prepare p as select now() > now() - interval '$1';` I think the reason is because `now() - $1` expects $1 to be a `timestamp` and `timestamp` [math] `timestamp` is always an interval. How can I get PHP to send this prepare statement?

Comment: @Steve: I don't think your proposal works. If you `execute p('-2 minutes')` you get a wrong result. Same thing if you `execute p('whatever')`. I'm not even sure what it computes.

Comment: @Steve: the multiplication is not a kludge, it's the generally recommended solution. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14465727/how-to-insert-things-like-now-interval-2-minutes-into-php-pdo-query as well