# How do I bind an INTERVAL param with PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a query that I am trying to set up entirely from bound parameters, but right now I'm having to resort to appending a string from a GET parameter (I don't really want to do that).

Here's my solution right now:

```
$interval = !empty($_REQUEST['interval']) ? $_REQUEST['interval'] : '28 DAY';
$interval = str_replace('_', ' ', $interval);

$data = array(
    ':msisdn' => $_REQUEST['msisdn']
);

$sql = <<<SQL
SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS `countup`
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            utc.`id_user`
        FROM
            `user_to_cli` utc
        WHERE
            1=1
            AND utc.`cli` = :msisdn
            AND utc.`dts_start` > CURDATE() - INTERVAL $interval
    ) a
;
SQL;
```

This works fine, but when I try to change the interval to a bound parameter, like so:

```
$interval = !empty($_REQUEST['interval']) ? $_REQUEST['interval'] : '28 DAY';
$interval = str_replace('_', ' ', $interval);

$data = array(
    ':msisdn' => $_REQUEST['msisdn'],
    ':interval' => $interval
);

$sql = <<<SQL
SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS `countup`
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            `user_to_cli` utc
        WHERE
            1=1
            AND utc.`cli` = :msisdn
            AND utc.`dts_start` > CURDATE() - INTERVAL :interval
    ) a
;
SQL;
```

I get the following error:

```
Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ') a'
```

Comment: `28 DAY` is more of a syntax construct than a value. Binding the numeric part might work (either per ->bindParam typing, or per SQL cast `INTERVAL (1*?) DAY`).

Comment: This works if I just bind the 28 instead of 28 DAY, but I wanted the ability to also select by HOUR, MONTH, etc.

Comment: I guess you won't be able to parameterize `DAY`, `MONTH` `YEAR` and the like. I would really use a custom whitelist filter there. (Certainly less effort than an inline`CASE` / probably not even feasible.)

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14465727/how-to-insert-things-like-now-interval-2-minutes-into-php-pdo-query

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code tries to use a bind variable to replace a SQL keyword as well as a number. You Can't Do That™.

When I've solved this problem I've translated my time intervals to seconds then used

```
 CURDATE() - INTERVAL :seconds SECONDS
```

By the way, CURDATE() gives you midnight today. You may want NOW() instead if you're handling sub-day intervals.