# Using mysql's INTERVAL with prepared statement

Tags: php, mysqli, bindparam

I prepare my DB request for prevent SQL injection with the extension Mysqlnd.
A request like this work on my site :

```
SELECT a, b FROM table where a = ?;
```

This next request doesn't work on my site:

```
SELECT a, b FROM table where b > DATE_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),INTERVAL ? ?);
```

> Error log : PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function execute() on a non-object in ..."
>   This is because the syntax of the request is wrong.

When I try it in my DB IDE, the double question mark count as one and not as 2 parameters.
[image]

How can I resolve this problem ?

Comment: I have not tested it, but I would assume you cannot parameterise the DAY/WEEK/... part of that query

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54128115/how-do-i-bind-an-interval-param-with-pdo help?

Comment: @NigelRen no really helpful because I want to choose with my parameter if it's a MONTH/DAY/HOUR/...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a placeholder, you can bind only data literals, in other words - strings and numbers.

`INTERVAL` accepts two arguments, `expression` and `unit`.

While the `expression` part is a number and can be bound all right, the `unit` part is a *keyword* and therefore cannot be bound. So you can only whitelist it. Here is a [white-listing function](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo_examples/order_by) I wrote that could help with the matter.

```
$unit = white_list($_GET['unit'], ["DAY","MINUTE","SECOND"], "Invalid time unit name");
$sql = "SELECT a, b FROM table where b > DATE_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),INTERVAL ? $unit)";
```

it is not very tidy but at least concise and safe.

Comment: Or instead of white_list just use PHP's native `in_array` function

Comment: `$unit = in_array($_GET['unit'], ["DAY","MINUTE","SECOND"]) ? $_GET['unit'] : "Invalid";`

Comment: `$unit = "Invalid"` will result in SQL error

Comment: instead of `: "Invalid"` you can exit() die() throw new error etc

Comment: so it won't be "just in_array()" anymore but a chunk of PHP code. Then, for simplicity you may want to wrap it in a user-defined function. And call it white_list()

Answer (score 0):

Whitout extra functions, and the full INTERVAL list:

```
$timeFormat = "MINUTE"; //get the $timeFormat value from elsewhere
$timeFormatWhitelist = array("MICROSECOND","SECOND","MINUTE","HOUR","DAY","WEEK","MONTH","QUARTER","YEAR","SECOND_MICROSECOND","MINUTE_MICROSECOND","MINUTE_SECOND","HOUR_MICROSECOND","HOUR_SECOND","HOUR_MINUTE","DAY_MICROSECOND","DAY_SECOND","DAY_MINUTE","DAY_HOUR","YEAR_MONTH");

if (in_array($timeFormat, $timeFormatWhitelist)) {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE `dateTime` <= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),INTERVAL ? $timeFormat)";
    // your prepared statement and do something with the result
}
```