# DATE_ADD sql in PHP PDO

Tags: php, sql, pdo, dateadd

I am trying to insert a new row in my database with a date and the same date plus 1 week.

I use PDO in php, don't know if it is relevant.

This is the code which fails:

```
$stmtEncInsert = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO test
                                        (id_Event,   NIF,  name , description,  image,  start_date, end_date) 
VALUES (:idOfEvent, :NIF, :name, :description, :image, :startDate, DATE_ADD(:date_end,INTERVAL 1 WEEK)
                                        )");

        $stmtEncInsert->execute(array(':idOfEvent' => $idOfEvent, ':NIF'=> $NIF, ':name' => $resEnc['name'], ':description' => $resEnc['description'],
                                      ':image' => $resEnc['image'], ':startDate' => $date_end, ':date_end' => $date_end));
```

I get some data from other queries (example: $resEnc['..']) but all data is ok. I tried to print in a file all data and all of them are ok, they exist.

The problem is that the last field (end_date) is always giving error, always says: you cannot leave this field empty...

I think it is problem from DATE_ADD or so, but I haven't found anything related to this.

I tested deleting DATE_ADD and just using the current_date and it works so I guess this is the problem.

Any idea?

I use MySQL as engine

This is the output of the exception given:

```
 Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'end_date' cannot be null
```

$date_end contains 0000-00-00 it is a valid date and field is DATE type got from DB from another query

Comment: you need to learn to debug your code

Comment: As a general advice: always post the actual error messages (you can use the clipboard so you don't need to type) rather than your interpretation of them. Furthermore, if there's a problem with `DATE_ADD(:date_end,INTERVAL 1 WEEK)`, how can we diagnose anything if we don't know what `:date_end` contains? If `$date_end` is `"Dog"` it'd be fairly obvious why it's failing.

Comment: I already added more info

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067782/php-pdo-insert-current-date-plus-one-month-into-mysql

Have a read dude, it's basically unable to accept DATE_ADD as part of the prepare. So do it in the bind_value.

Comment: You do not need `:date_end` while preparing. Simply use `:startDate`.

Comment: @John - That question is about embedding MySQL functions in PHP code. Nobody's doing anything remotely similar here. // @hjpotter92 - Using 2 parameters is more portable that re-using `:date_end`, which is not official supported by PDO and miserably fails with some MySQL drivers. // This question's problem has nothing to do with PHP as far as I can tell.

Comment: I also tried just with one parameter instead 2 but it fails because it needs another one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`0000-00-00` is *not* a valid date. MySQL can be configured to store invalid or incomplete dates, but that doesn't make them valid. As such, attempting to add one week will not return a valid date but `NULL`:

```
mysql> SELECT DATE_ADD('0000-00-00', INTERVAL 1 WEEK);
+-----------------------------------------+
| DATE_ADD('0000-00-00', INTERVAL 1 WEEK) |
+-----------------------------------------+
| NULL                                    |
+-----------------------------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.03 sec)
```

To sum up: as the error message explains, if you've designed `end_date` to be mandatory, it cannot be empty. Either assign it a proper value or allow it to be `NULL`.

---

**Edit #1:** If you want to force that `'0000-00-00'` plus 1 week equals `'0000-00-00'` you can do this:

```
COALESCE(DATE_ADD('0000-00-00', INTERVAL 1 WEEK), '0000-00-00')
```

*IMHO, dealing with '0000-00-00' dates does not provide any benefit and makes everything more convoluted but it's your code anyway ;-)*

**Edit #2:** Users don't type zeroes in field dates. Your PHP code needs to detect empty dates and insert `NULL`:

```
if( is_valid_date($_POST['start_date']) ){
    $start_date = $_POST['start_date'];
}else{
    $start_date = NULL;
}
$stmtEncInsert = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO test (start_date) VALUES (:start_date)");
$stmtEncInsert->execute(
    array('test_date' => $start_date),
);
```

But you have a database design problem: the `end_date` column is mandatory, yet users are not required to enter it.

Comment: If I try the same in heidiSQL, just using '0000-00-00' it works. So, maybe the date is wrong but it works outside php. I tried right now to create a date in php as argument like this: date(...) but also fails

Comment: No offence but you need to stop trying random stuff and reporting back with vague descriptions of what you've done. Make sure you *understand* the answers you get and ask for clarifications if you don't. Whatever, please see my edit.

Comment: No offence, don't worry. I am here to learn. I tried creating another row with other date: 2013-03-05 and it works. Were you talking about 0000-00-00 was an incorrect date because of the numbers? I though because of the form. Most of the rows I read are created by other users and they don't set the date, so it takes 0000-00-00 so I have to deal with it also.

Comment: Yes, I have to check zeroes from users but in this query the user doesn't insert the date, it is taken from database from other user's query. but I will take care about zeroes right now. Thank you so much

Comment: I think you misread my advice. I was suggesting not to use zeroes at all, so you don't need to take care of them. The standard SQL value for "empty" is `NULL`—and PHP supports it as well.

Comment: Oh, yes I misunderstood it. Yeah, maybe it is better not allowing them. Thanks again. I will check all again to find if I leave any place where you can write zeroes